# Evan's Purchase Order example: Shouldn't parts be synchronized with PO within single transaction?

Tags: domain-driven-design

On page 134 ( [DDD: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) ) author improves *Purchase Order model* by making `Purchase Order` **PO** an *Aggregate Root* containing `PO Line Items`, while `Part` entity is made a root of its own *Aggregate* ( making `Part` an *Aggregate root* does make sense, since *parts* will be shared by many **POs** ):

> An implementation consistennt with this model would guarantee the
>   invariant relating PO and its items, while changes to the price of a
>   part would not have to immediately affect the items that reference it.
>
> ...
>
> But this is not an invariant that must be enforced at all times. By
>   making the dependency of line items on parts looser, we avoid
>   contention and reflect the realities of the business better. At the
>   same time, tightening the relationship of the PO and its line items
>   guarantees that an important business rule will be followed.

Author argues that changes to the *part prices* don't have to immediately propagate to the ***PO*** aggregates that reference it, since:

- locking the *part* when particular **PO** is being updated may cause contention ( due to the possibility of several **POs** simulaneously trying to get a lock on the same *part*  )
- *parts* get modified less frequently than **POs** and as such chances of **POs** having invalid data are relatively small

a) I understand author's arguments, but shouldn't the consistency of **PO** be a top priority in such a model and as such *parts* should be locked together with **POs** being updated, even at the risk of contention?

b) In contrast, on pages 176, 177 author did find it necessary to enforce invariants spanning two aggregates within single transaction ( ie when `Handling Event` is added, `Delivery History` should also be updated accordingly within the same transaction ):

> The Delivery History holds a collection of Handling Events relevant to
>   its Cargo and new object must be added to this collection as part of
>   the transaction. If this back-pointer were not created, the objects
>   would be inconsistent.
>
> ...
>
> The need to update Delivery History when adding a Handling Event gets
>   the Cargo AGGREGATE involved in the transaction.

I can't figure out why would maintaining consistency within single transaction be more important in this example than in **PO** example?

Note ( I'm assuming that by *"back-pointer"* he's referring to `Handling Event` instance? )

c) Is there a particular reason why author didn't as an alternative propose an implementation of  *Optimistic Concurency check*, where *Parts table* would contain a *rowversion* field, which our code would inspect each time some **PO** was being updated?

d) Btw, why must `Price` value be copied into `Line Item` ( Figure 6.11, page 134 )? Can't *PO*'s invariants check the price by inspecting `Part` entity?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PO, once placed, can be regarded as an immutable event. This is why the price value must be copied. Future changes in price should not be reflected on existing POs - that would be a violation of business rules. This is why the relationship between a PO and the Part can and should be loosened. This is also why these consistency characteristics apply to a PO but not in the other scenario.

Comment: If regarding PO ( once placed ) as immutable is a business rule, then I assume it also means PO ( ie objects within PO aggregate ) also shouldn't be edited once this PO is placed?

Comment: Yes. However, this may depend on the nature of the PO. Sometimes a PO can be placed, however it can have status updates. In this case, the PO items remain the same, however new statuses are added.

Comment: Just to be sure, is author using the term "back-pointer" to refer to Handling Event instance?

Comment: Yes, he's referring to pointers, as in object references, between handling event and history. This is different from an identity reference.

Comment: Uhm, I'm almost sure that he's referring to the fact that Handling Even is pointing back to Cargo ( ie one of its properties is referencing Cargo )?! I'm assuming this since in book he's talking about cycle of references from Cargo to Delivery History to Handling Event and back to Cargo and due to the use of word "back"?! Though I'm not completely sure

Comment: You're probably right, I didn't take a look at the book while answering this time. A pointer implies an object reference, I'm just not sure which entities are referenced.